# Updating config files within the script that references them?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, configuration

I have no problem adding config files to a given script, but automatically updating them is another matter. In this instance I'm providing a few variables to a script, and I'd like the script to be able to change the values provided by the config file. Is there a standard way to change the value of a variable in a running script, and then update the config file accordingly? My current approach is sed-ing for the line containing the variable and changing its contents, but I feel like there must be a better way.

For example, imagine a program that generates some arbitrary text file:
*Line in config file, defining a variable available to the program:*

```
EXIT_ON_GEN="true" //exit on successful generation of text file if true
```

The user selects a menu option that indicates they would like to stay in the program instead, because they like generating arbitrary text so much. It would be easy to simply set it to false for the current instance of the program, but what's the best way to change the config file itself, so the user doesn't have to go back and change the settings each time they run it?

Comment: It would help if you provided some _brief_ and _specific_ examples showing what you want.

Comment: ed, sed and perl are all very good at editing files in-place.

Comment: @John1024 I added a fairly brief and specific example, though I wasn't sure if you meant specific in relation to my intent or the actual purpose of the script. Also, I meant to write that I used sed to handle the find and replace, but I use grep far more often and absent-mindedly put that in by mistake.

Comment: @user67459 What makes you unhappy with the sed approach?

Comment: It's not so much that I don't like it- it's easy enough to use and it can generally be done in a single line. I'm content to keep using it, but I know that so many Linux utilities make use of config files, so I was thinking that there may be some specific command or set of commands to make handling such things a little easier. Still, it makes sense to simply use sed or awk.

Comment: @user67459 That would be nice.  I think the problem is that unix/linux never settled on a single config file format.  Consequently, there is no general tool to handle them.

Comment: Ah, that explains it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `sed`

Starting with this file:

```
$ cat >file
EXIT_ON_GEN="true" //exit on successful generation of text file if true
```

One method for changing true to false (and displaying the new version on the terminal) would use sed:

```
$ sed 's/^EXIT_ON_GEN=[^[:space:]]*/EXIT_ON_GEN="false"/' file
EXIT_ON_GEN="false" //exit on successful generation of text file if true
```

To instead make the change to the file in place, use the `-i` option:

```
$ sed -i 's/^EXIT_ON_GEN=[^[:space:]]*/EXIT_ON_GEN="false"/' file
```

#### Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='"' '/^EXIT_ON_GEN/{$2="false"} 1' file
EXIT_ON_GEN="false" //exit on successful generation of text file if true
```